# C# using VTK to rotate a 3D object

Tags: c#, 3d, vtk

I am trying to using a rotary knob to rotate a 3D object in real time along its x, y, and z axis.

This is going to be developed with C# and VTK. I am brand new to VTK, so I am wondering is there an example that can get me started? I think this should not be very hard, and there should be existing functionality in VTK that can do the job.

I imaging this should be something that looks like. The knobs boxed in orange should be able to rotate the object in the left panel along its x (red), y (green), and z (gren) axis:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just call things like

`actor->RotateY(45);`

This is demonstrated here:
http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/RotateActor